# Can't get this form to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that needs to update a user objects attributes.

Here are the three steps that I've boiled down to:

1. the action 'new' needs to provide the form with an object to manipulate
2. The form needs to know which object to collect values for
3. when the form is submitted it needs to send these params to a function that updates the user object

If all this is kosher here's what I've done to try and make this happen.

Within the 'new' action I've attempted to provide the user object like so:

```
      @current_user  = current_user
```

Then, in the view this is what the form looks like:

```
<%= form_for (@current_user) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :target_bf_pct %>
   <%= f.text_field :target_bf_pct %>

   <%= f.label :activity_factor %>
   <%= options_for_select([['Sedentary (Desk Job)', 1.2],
                                           ['Light Activity (1-3 day a week)', 1.35],
                                           ['Moderate Activity (3-5 days a week)', 1.55],
                                           ['Very Active ( 6-7 days a week)', 1.75],
                                           ['Extremely Active (Atheletic Endurance)', 1.95]])
%>

  <%# f.submit "Post", class:"btn btn-large btn-primary" %> 
<% end %>
```

The error I'm getting at this point is this:

```
undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd943d00d08>:0x007fd944e5b6c0>
```

which is referring to the forms @current_user object that's supposed to correspond to the @current_user instance within the new action...

Important note:

1. I'm using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for my sessions controller to create new users and handle sessions.
2. I don't believe that my use of the form helper options_for_select is being used properly since I've yet to assign it a value it's supposed to represent once selected like "activity_factor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for(@current_user) do |f| %>
            ^ no space please :)
```

This is not a joke.

```
<%= form_for (@current_user) do |f| %>
```

will work, but, for example:

```
<%= form_for (@current_user, :class => "user_form") do |f| %>
```

will not. With space you're on the way to do mistakes like that.

The second one. Your environment doesn't know **user_path**

Add to routes.rb (even if devise's statements exist):

```
resources :users
```

Comment: lol ok I'll make sure not those. I tend to add spaces like these everywhere.

Comment: Adding resources :users did it! Thanks! I also removed the spaces. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

This error is probably coming from the `form_for` helper. It's trying to figure out the `action` URL for the form, so it observes that `@current_user` is a `User`, so calls `user_path(@current_user)`. If the method is not defined, that usually means that there is no route defined for `users#update`.

Try running `rake routes` and confirm that the `users#update` route is present. If not, add it and try again.

*Also, a few notes:*

- If you're looking to update an existing user, the form should probably be in the `edit` action. The `new` action is usually reserved for creating brand new users.
- The `current_user` helper is accessible in both the controller and the view. So, you could use `current_user` directly in the view; setting it in the controller is a bit redundant. Just a small thing.
- Devise offers its own `users#edit` form and `users#update` action for changing passwords and the like. I'm not sure on the details, but it seems likely that Devise makes it easy to override the existing form, so long as all the fields you want to edit are marked as `attr_accessible`. If it would be appropriate to merge these fields into the existing Devise form, that might be worth some research.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matchu! I'm looking into everything you've suggested now.